# What is the average log-perplexity in seq2seq modules in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Output of the  following tensorflow function should give average log perplexity. I went through the source code. But I don't understand how they calculate that loss.

```
tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, targets, weights, average_across_timesteps=True, average_across_batch=True, softmax_loss_function=None, name=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the tensorflow implementation. Through the perplexity has some broad meaning here in this function perplexity means

**two to the power of your total cross entropy loss.**

Please refer the [first answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/what-is-perplexity) of this question.